# How to config a Linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How do I config my linked server to connect to the other database with following properties:

```
ServerName:saleh
user:sa
password:....
Computer IP address:192.168.100.146
```

Comment: You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(v=SQL.80).aspx), and I dont think this belongs to SO. flagging for migration.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution my self. so I'll share it here

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver

    @server = 'saleh',
    @srvproduct = '',
    @provider = 'MSDASQL',
    @provstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.100.147;UID=sa;PWD=123456;'
```